# What sort of issue would generate an E_COMPILE_WARNING in PHP?

Tags: php

I've spent a bit searching *The Google* as well as *SO* and have been unable to find an answer for this simple question:

### What sort of issue would generate an `E_COMPILE_WARNING` in PHP?

The [**PHP manual entry on the subject** <sup>*docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) says of `E_COMPILE_WARNING`:

> Compile-time warnings (non-fatal errors). This is like an E_WARNING,
>   except it is generated by the Zend Scripting Engine.

But I'm not sure what this would constitute. What's the difference between a regular `E_WARNING` and a warning raised by the Zend Scripting Engine? Could someone please explain and provide a code snippet if applicable?

Comment: and the code generating the warning is?

Comment: @Dagon Exactly, that's the question. :)

Comment: You can see in the PHP source where those warnings are issued: http://lxr.php.net/search?q=%22zend_error%28E_COMPILE_WARNING%22&project=PHP_TRUNK

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, the difference between an `E_WARNING` and an `E_COMPILE_WARNING` is that `E_COMPILE_WARNING` is generated while the script is still compiling.

`E_COMPILE_WARNING` is similar to `E_COMPILE_ERROR` in that it is generated during compile time, but an `E_COMPILE_WARNING` does not prevent script execution the way `E_COMPILE_ERROR` does.  Compare it to the the relation between `E_ERROR` and `E_WARNING`, where the former halts execution, and the latter allows execution to continue.

For example, the following code generates an `E_COMPILE_WARNING`:

```
<?php
    echo "\n";
    echo "Hello World";
    echo "\n\n";
    var_dump(error_get_last());
    declare(foo='bar');
?>
```

output:

```
Warning: Unsupported declare 'foo' in e_compile_warning.php on line 6

Hello World

array(4) {
  ["type"]=>
  int(128)
  ["message"]=>
  string(25) "Unsupported declare 'foo'"
  ["file"]=>
  string(124) "e_compile_warning.php"
  ["line"]=>
  int(6)
}
```

Notice how the warning is displayed before the other output (even though "Hello World" came first in the source), and the `var_dump` statement on line 5 references an error that occurs on line 6.  PHP compiles the script, doesn't like `declare(foo='bar');`, but goes back and executes the script anyway (as opposed to an `E_COMPILE_ERROR` like `$this = 2;`, which would stop execution (and compilation) immediately).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can produce the output warning directly using the following code:

```
$cmd = "declare(foo='bar');";
eval($cmd);
```